# Eclipse Mars 2 Console doesn't show building process

Tags: java, eclipse, console, building, sql-server-mars

since some days ago the console output window doesn't show nor the building process neither the the building errors any more.

The window remains white, even if I build all the projects - as well as the progress-window.

The console still shows the running output of the projects and if the code is ok, the projects are working. So I think the compilation is working, but not shown.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: uhm, try `Window>show view>Progress` and `window>show view>other..>general>Problems`?

Comment: (in case your "progress" and "problems" views are not visible)

Comment: Thaks 4 the quick answer. Both are open - and they don't show anything.

Comment: uhm if you add some invalid code (so that it is underlined in red in the code editor), does an error appear in the "problems" view?

Comment: or, check that Project>build automatically is selected; then try Project>clean>clean all projects

Comment: When it's compiled, the error appears in the problem's window.

Comment: ok, so it is displaying the build errors, right (?)

Comment: Ok, now clean all projects is also done without rebuilding any new projects.

Comment: Yes, it does. Now building the project from scratch it shows 5 warnings. 1 of them is: Build path specific environment Java SE 1.7. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment. And for about half a second a new window appears and disappears.

Comment: ..ok and now - compiling a longer project I've seen the window. It's a window with a progress bar, which shows the progress of the build process and disappears after the end of the process. But the steps of compilation are not written anymore in the console window.

Comment: usually the compilation output is not written to the console, if that is a (simple) eclipse project. But if the project is based on maven, you can run it as `mvn package`, and in that case the (maven) output is shown in the console